# Apache Spark Worker Nodes unable to find my application classes

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Using **apache spark 1.6** in a **standalone cluster mode** with a **Master** and **few Workers** in a **single machine** having **Windows 7 OS**.

I created spark context within java application and wrote few classes (e.g. **MyFunction** which extends **org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function**) in order to perform transformation on data. I called it like

```
javaRDD.map(new MyFunction());
```

**Unfortunately**, Spark Workers does not find MyFunction class and job terminated with ClassNotFoundException...

I did some research and found a method **SparkConf.setJars(jars)**. So, i build my application into jar (**myapp.jar**) and placed it in a directory (e.g. **D:/spark**)

```
String[] jars = { "file:D:/spark/myappjar" };
sparkConf.setJars(jars);
```

But it leads to Exception:

```
2016-03-30 15:27:07 WARN  TaskSetManager:70 
- Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, alivia): 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ai.cache.spark.NumericFieldsToVector
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
```

**Questions:**

1. How do i make the application's own class files available to Spark
   Worker from Spark Driver Program
2. If i need to provide jar of my application to Spark Driver Program,
   How can i do that. (The sparkConf.setJars() mothod failed for me as
   described above)

Comment: What build tool are you using in your project?

Comment: @Ernest Kiwele I am using Maven as a build tool for this project

Comment: OK, I'll update the answer also given your comment under the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to both 1 and 2 is that you can simplify the packaging of your code (both the driver code and what's needed by workers) by creating a fat/uber jar that will be used both on the driver and the workers.

As documented on the 'Submitting Applications' page (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html), the way to resolve these issues is to build your project's code, bundling it with all its dependencies into a single jar file that you could then set as you did in your code.

From that page:

*If your code depends on other projects, you will need to package them alongside your application in order to distribute the code to a Spark cluster. To do this, create an assembly jar (or “uber” jar) containing your code and its dependencies. Both sbt and Maven have assembly plugins. When creating assembly jars, list Spark and Hadoop as provided dependencies; these need not be bundled since they are provided by the cluster manager at runtime. Once you have an assembled jar you can call the bin/spark-submit script as shown here while passing your jar.*

You can then use the fat jar to run the driver and to supply all classes needed by workers.

**UPDATE** (given details in comments):
As you're deploying a web application to an application server, your best way to resolve this is to (IMO):

1. Structure your project to split web-specific code from Spark client code (code for the driver and workers)
2. Make the web project depend on the spark client Jar, then use the JAR file in call to setJars().

That can be done as follows:

**Create JAR maven project to be used for spark-related code**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.company.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo-spark-client</artifactId>
  ...
  <!--Add spark-related dependencies as per your current setup-->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  <!-- Add the plugin to create the uber/fat jar file -->
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactSet>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-fat.jar</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

**Create a web project that depends on the previous artifact**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.company.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo-web</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  ...
  <!--Add spark client dependency -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>foo-spark-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

***Note that you may need to re-add here spark dependencies as they are marked as 'provided' in the dependency, but may actually be needed at runtime.***

Now, your Sark driver code must be in the web project as that's the one expected to run the driver (as you suggested).

With this all you have to do is call setJars with the path to the uber jar of com.company.foo:foo-spark-client artifact. This jar will be created in the foo-spark-client project's target folder (with '-fat.jar' appended to the name). Put this JAR on an accessible path on the server running Tomcat, then update your web code accordingly:

```
String[] jars = { "file:D:/foo-spark-client/target/foo-spark-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT-fat.jar" };
sparkConf.setJars(jars);
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. The application i am developing is web application hosted on tomcat server. I run spark cluster manually (via command prompt) on the same local machine. Then i create SparkContext in my web application and set the jar in spark context using `sparkConf.setJars(jars);` and when i execute a job ,the spark context is unable to find **myapp.jar**. Can you help me in this regard